# Get Cannot use import statement outside a module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm quite new to node.js and following a tutorial, using `node v13.6.0` .
I'd like to import `is-empty'`  into this file:

```
const Validator = require('validator');

import isEmpty from './is-empty';

module.exports = function validateRegisterInput(data) {
    
    let errors = {};

    if(Validator.isLength(data.name), {min:2, max: 30}) {
        errors.name = 'name is too short or too long';
        }
    return {
        errors, 
        isValid: isEmpty(errors)
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1060:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1108:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/myapp/routes/api/users.js:12:31)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/myapp/server.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:30)
```

`is-empty`is  defined like this:

```
const isEmpty = value =>
    value === undefined ||
    value === null ||
    (typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
    (typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0);

    module.exports = isEmpty
```

I'm wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: Use ``require()``.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes is it some new change in node? In my 2018 tutorial, it works as above.

Comment: It looks like you are now combining esm syntax in your cjs module. Just use only one style of module would resolve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using require instead of import as documented in https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field

```js
const Validator = require('validator');

const isEmpty = require('./is-empty');

module.exports = function validateRegisterInput(data) {
    
    let errors = {};

    if(Validator.isLength(data.name), {min:2, max: 30}) {
        errors.name = 'name is too short or too long';
        }
    return {
        errors, 
        isValid: isEmpty(errors)
    }
}
``
```

Comment: Is it something new? Because the `import` above`  worked fine on the tutorial which I'm learning from.

Answer (score 0):

What they're trying to say is that you cannot mix the two. You can use ESM and use only `require`s or you can use `import`s. Since Node already treats your javascript as commonJS modules, you can use imports, but the moment you introduce require, the whole thing falls over.

I've just been through this with an old protractor project that was using requires. It's all or nothing, one or the other.

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs

> Using require to load an ES module is not supported because ES modules have asynchronous execution. Instead, use import() to load an ES module from a CommonJS module.

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs

> No require, exports or module.exports
> In most cases, the ES module import can be used to load CommonJS modules.
> If needed, a require function can be constructed within an ES module using module.createRequire().